# Creating reports for each unique value in column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to find an answer if it possible to automate creating powerBI reports for each unique value in one of columns(It's like filtering on whole report for one of the values and publish report than change value to next one and repeat steps for other values)? Is there any fast way to do it? I wrote program to filtering via link and clicking mouse than save links for each person to excel but i wonder if there is more reliable and faster way to do it. I am using PowerBI premium for user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically called "Report Bursting", or "Data Driven Subscriptions", and here's a [walkthrough](https://guyinacube.com/2021/04/28/report-bursting-with-the-power-platform/) of how to do it with Power Automate and Power BI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I watched it and it is almost excatly what i need(I want to sent link for powerBI for each person so they can use filters etc but don't see each others reports but I guess it will only require to select proper option in Power Automate so I will try to figure it out later when i have more time to do it). Thanks one more time for help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you leverage RLS instead of hardcoding filters?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for my late response. I am creating this for people outside the organisation and sendig them a link to powerBI report. If i understand RLS correctly from the video i watched it can be only apply for people that have to log in to powerBI service first.

Comment: Unless you are using PBI Embedded in a applicational way or you are publishing to web, every other scenario will have to use a specific Power BI user.
The users outside of your organization are invited in your Azure B2B? If so, then you can still leverage RLS.

Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-azure-ad-b2b

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check it out.